# How do I set an active Spring boot profile on the command line using "spring-boot:run"?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, command-line, profile, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.8 and Spring Boot 1.5.  I'm using Windows PowerShell, for whatever that's worth.  How do I start my Spring Boot project and set an active profile on the command line?  I tried

```
> mvn -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev spring-boot:run
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.247 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-25T16:06:50-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".run.profiles=dev". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

but the "-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev" switch doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows PowerShell, try using

```
mvn spring-boot:run --define spring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=dev"
```

Answer (score -1):

`-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev` is for Spring Boot 2.x

You should use `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` for Spring Boot 1.x

Docs: [Spring Boot 1.5 Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried 'mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=dev spring-boot:run' but still got the error '[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".profiles.active=dev".'

Comment: It is not working for me. Literally found nothing on the internet.